# add an extended property in Azure Ad which will be accessible across groups in AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

i wanted to add an extended property in Azure Ad which will be accessible across groups in AD.Got this
POST   https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/applications//extensionProperties?api-version=1.21-preview  { “name”: “skypeId”, “dataType”: “String”, “targetObjects”: [“User”] }

Wanted to understand 2 things which the document is not clear to me on:-
1.if the "targetObjects" is specified as user will the extended property appear across groups as well as users in an application
2.can this be done directly via azure portal without using the  https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/ as mentioned in the document
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#RegisterAnExtension

Does anybody have an idea on this?

Comment: Extension properties can only be registered via APIs at the moment as far as I know.

Comment: u mean the graphapi?

Comment: Yeah, Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph API (this one is recommended these days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the "targetObjects" is specified as user will the extended property
>   appear across groups as well as users in an application

You set the "targetObjects" as the user, that means this extended property will be added in the user's attributes and also can appear across groups as well as users in this application.

> can this be done directly via the Azure portal

For now, you cannot do this via the Azure portal. You could do this by using Azure AD Graph API(you tried) or Microsoft Graph API,  or you can also use AAD PowerShell.

If you persist in doing this via the portal, the [B2C portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) is suggested for you. You could manually define a custom attribute for the user. For the details, you could read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr).

Using Microsoft Graph API:

```html
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions
Content-type: application/json

{
    "id":"graphlearn_courses",
    "description": "Graph Learn training courses extensions",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Group"
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "courseId",
            "type": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "name": "courseName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "courseType",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

For the details, you could read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions).

Using AAD PowerShell:

```html
Set-AzureADUserExtension
   -ObjectId <String>
   -ExtensionName <String>
   -ExtensionValue <String>
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduserextension?view=azureadps-2.0).